# EditText getText() returns different value then what is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have been developing android for a while now and have never come across this before so im hoping some one here can help. I have multiple EditText's and autocompleTextViews that populate themselves from sharedprefs. The problem is that the views are not displaying the text they should be. They display the old value that was there until i leave the activity and come back. The strange part is that if i call the getText function on the editText when it has the wrong value displayed getText() returns the correct value. Can someone please explain why this might be.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_info, container, false);
         myPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        initPrefs();
        findTextViews();
        findViews();                
        initDataSource();
        runQueries();           
        getAllFields();

        return view;
}
private void findViews() {

    EditPayID = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById( R.id.EditpayID );
    EditPayID.setText(PayIDPref);
    Log.e("findviews",EditPayID.getText().toString());      
            //^^ correct value but screen still displays wrong value
}
private void initPrefs(){
     editor = myPrefs.edit();                
     PayIDPref = myPrefs.getString("PayID", "");
     Log.e("payidPref", PayIDPref);


}
```

The following code I think is unrelated to the problem but maybe I am missing something
this is all of the code associated with payID

```
EditPayID.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            EditPayID.showDropDown();
            EditPayID.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
                @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        String selected = EditPayID.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();
                        EditPayID.setText(selected);
                        editor.putString("PayID" ,selected); 
                        editor.apply();
                    }                       
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
        EditPayID.setValidator(new android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.Validator() {

            @Override
            public boolean isValid(CharSequence text) {
                Log.e("in pay isValid" , "validating");
                Collections.sort(validPays);
                if (Collections.binarySearch(validPays, text.toString()) >= 0){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence fixText(CharSequence invalidText) {
                EditPayID.setError("You have Entered invalid PayID");
                editor.putString("PayID" ,"Invalid PayID");
                editor.apply();
                return "Invalid PayID";             
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you provide a code ?

Comment: I can but im not especially sure it will help. Ill post it shortly

Comment: it seems your are not saving properly the new value on your shared preferences.

Comment: I agree with @Tobiel. What happens if you add a `Log.e` statement after `findViews` in `onCreateView`? Does it print correct value or not?

Comment: But I am as I have stated the getText method returns the correct value that the edit text should be displaying but the screen doesnt show it. If the page is closed and reloaded the view then has the correct value

Comment: It still displays the correct value in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by calling finsViews() and initPrefs() in my onResume() Method. Although I am not sure why this solved the issues seeing that these two methods were being called from the oncreate whenever I cam to the Fragment. If someone could explain this further It'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you tell me what is finsViews() i cant find this method.

Comment: I think @KBusc means : findViews().

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi: findViews() & initPrefs() are his own methods, which are  re-initializing the EditTexts are setting the texts again.